# Absolute external links bug, url of the current page added at the beginning of the url

Tags: wordpress, url, absolute-path

I have a very strange external links behavior on this page:

https://dev.switchonpaper.site/en/daniel-g-andujar-the-artist-as-a-thinker-and-augur-of-what-happens/

There is a list of external links visible by clicking on "Go Deeper".
**On some links, the address of the current page is added at the beginning of the external link.**

E.g.: iSAM™ (1997)
E.g.: TTTP Photo Collection - 1997

All external links are absolute links.
When you look at the source code, the links are correct.
This site runs under Wordpress, the links are contained in a Gutenberg block built with the ACF plugin.

I tested the following things:

- Disable all plugins.
  The browser or something else continues to add the current page address on some links only.
- I emptied the server cache, removed all the .htaccess rules except the wordpress part.
- I made sure that the PHP file that writes these links is in UTF-8.
- By recreating the links, it is always the same ones who are affected.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?
Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the so called "hidden characters" before your link start. I suggest you to check it by yourself with some online tool like this: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php. If you try to paste there the link copied by your source code you will see you have hidden stuff before "https:..."

[image: Hidden character]

The solution to this issue is that you delete all the characters and you write them all over again by yourself, w/o copy/pasting them from another source or in alternative paste them inside some non-HTML text editor before pasting them to your website

Comment: Thank you so much Diego for the explanation!
I spend allmost 4 hours on this :/.
And for some reason the special char was tied to the H of "http", so just by deleting and rewriting it, it worked !